# Plotting the Kappa distribution function

Tags: plotting, physics

Does anybody know how to plot the Kappa distribution function encountered in plasma physics?

[image]

Comment: For [reference](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-plot-of-kappa-distributions-for-several-values-of-kappa-The-Maxwell-distribution_fig1_33416853).

Comment: @Syed thank you. but my question was from the same reference

Comment: One more [reference](https://lesia.obspm.fr/perso/michel-moncuquet/theseweb/tempioweb/node12.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not know the value of the thermal velocity, I simply set it to: 1. Then:

```
f[k_, x_] = (1 + x^2/(k 1^2))^(-k - 1);
funs[x_] = Table[f[k, x], {k, 2, 10}];
LogPlot[Evaluate@funs[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {0.0001, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much, I really appreciate that .

Comment: @lia you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to this answer.